# Power Chime Sounding at odd times 2018 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, audio, battery, sleep-wake

I recently bought a 15-inch 2018 i9 MacBook Pro. After a few days, I realized that whenever I close my laptop lid for the night, it keeps on periodically making the battery chiming noise every 7 minutes or so. When I took a look at the battery in the last 12 hours (right after periodic chiming), it was clear the battery has been 100% or very near 100% for a long time. When using the MacBook Pro during the day, I do not notice any periods where the laptop should be charging but the battery status indicates otherwise. However, I might not be paying careful enough attention. Are there any further steps I can take to resolve this issue?

[image: Battery full last 12 hours]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I fixed this by [resetting my System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).</s>

EDIT: 
this only temporarily fixed it. I ended up needing to exchange MacBooks.